# Integral of Gaussian over the standard simplex

Tags: integration, combinatorics, probability-distributions

Let $\Delta_{n-1}$ be the standard $(n-1)$-simplex, i.e., $\Delta_{n-1} = \{p_i \ge 0 | \sum_{i=1}^n p_i = 1\}$. I have the following random variable defined over $\Delta_{n-1}$,

$$
Y:=pCp:=\sum_{i,j=1}^n p_i p_j C_{i,j}
$$

where $C_{i,j}=C_{j,i} \in \mathbb{R}$, i.e., $C$ is a real symmetric matrix.

I am interested in the probability distribution of $Y$. I presume that obtaining the characteristic function (or the moment generating function) may be simpler, hence I'd be interested in

$$
M(\lambda) := \mathsf{E}_{\Delta_{n-1}} (e^{\lambda Y}) := \int_{\Delta_{n-1}}  e^{\lambda p C p}  \mu(dp)
$$

which explains the title. Here $\mu(dp)$ is the uniform (Dirichelet) distribution over the simplex $\Delta_{n-1}$ and $\mathsf{E}_{\Delta_{n-1}}$ the corresponding expectation value. Note that there is no issue of convergence so computing the moment generating function or the characteristic function seems equally hard.

It is possible to obtain the moments of $Y$ using the formula  [in here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_distribution#Moments), however the combinatorics is a bit (quite) awkward.

Since this question is somehow natural, before embarking in possibly re-inventing the wheel I wanted to check if anyone knows the answer already. Any pointer to the literature is also appreciated (I have not found anything myself).